# Catch Scrapy exception when crawling from Airflow

Tags: scrapy, airflow, google-cloud-composer, google-cloud-storage

I'm trying to catch the exception that occurs on my spider in a manner that I can mark the task instance as failed. Currently the task finishes and is marked as succeeded. I'm calling the `crawl()` from `PythonOperator` in Airflow, as follow:

```py
with DAG(
    'MySpider',
    default_args=default_args,
    schedule_interval=None) as dag:

    t1 = python_task = PythonOperator(
        task_id="crawler_task",
        python_callable=run_crawler,
        op_kwargs=dag_kwargs
    )
```

Here is my `run_crawler()` method:

```py
def run_crawler(**kwargs):
    project_settings = set_project_settings({
        'FEEDS': {
            f'{kwargs["bucket"]}%(time)s.{kwargs["format"]}': {
                'format': kwargs["format"],
                'encoding': 'utf8',
                'store_empty': kwargs["store_empty"]
            }
        }
    })
    
    print("Project settings: ")
    pprint(project_settings.attributes.items())

    set_connection("airflow", kwargs["gcs_connection_id"])
    
    process = CrawlerProcess(project_settings)
    process.crawl(spider.MySpider)

    print("Starting crawler...")
    process.start()
```

When running, I'm having problems with GCS credentials, which leads me to an Exception, as follow:

```
google.auth.exceptions.DefaultCredentialsError: The file /tmp/file_my_credentials.json does not have a valid type. Type is None, expected one of ('authorized_user', 'service_account', 'external_account', 'external_account_authorized_user', 'impersonated_service_account', 'gdch_service_account').

{logging_mixin.py:115} WARNING - [scrapy.statscollectors] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'downloader/request_bytes': 21087,
 'downloader/request_count': 68,
 'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 68,
 'downloader/response_bytes': 1863876,
 'downloader/response_count': 68,
 'downloader/response_status_count/200': 68,
 'elapsed_time_seconds': 25.647386,
 'feedexport/failed_count/GCSFeedStorage': 1,
 'httpcompression/response_bytes': 9212776,
 'httpcompression/response_count': 68,
 'item_scraped_count': 66,
 'log_count/DEBUG': 136,
 'log_count/ERROR': 1,
 'log_count/INFO': 10,
 'log_count/WARNING': 3,
 'memusage/max': 264441856,
 'memusage/startup': 264441856,
 'request_depth_max': 1,
 'response_received_count': 68,
 'scheduler/dequeued': 68,
 'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 68,
 'scheduler/enqueued': 68,
 'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 68,
[2032-13-13, 09:04:28 UTC] {engine.py:389} INFO - Spider closed (finished)
[2032-13-13, 09:04:28 UTC] {logging_mixin.py:115} WARNING - 
[scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
[2032-13-13, 09:04:28 UTC] {python.py:173} INFO - Done. Returned value was: None
[2032-13-13, 09:04:28 UTC] {taskinstance.py:1408} INFO - Marking task as SUCCESS. dag_id=MySpider, task_id=crawler_task, execution_date=2032-13-13, start_date=2032-13-13, end_date=2032-13-13
[2032-13-13, 09:04:28 UTC] {local_task_job.py:156} INFO - Task exited with return code 0
[2032-13-13, 09:04:28 UTC] {local_task_job.py:279} INFO - 0 downstream tasks scheduled from follow-on schedule check
```

As you can see, even having this exception, the task itself is marked as "SUCCESS". Is it possible to catch it in order to mark as FAILED, then we can follow it on airflow (Composer) interface?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why in this case the exception doesn't break the task.

You can add a `try` `except` in the `run_crawler` method and then raise you own exception in the `except` bloc :

```py
import logging

def run_crawler(**kwargs):
    class CustomException(Exception):
        pass

    try:
        project_settings = set_project_settings({
            'FEEDS': {
                f'{kwargs["bucket"]}%(time)s.{kwargs["format"]}': {
                    'format': kwargs["format"],
                    'encoding': 'utf8',
                    'store_empty': kwargs["store_empty"]
                }
            }
        })

        print("Project settings: ")
        pprint(project_settings.attributes.items())

        set_connection("airflow", kwargs["gcs_connection_id"])

        process = CrawlerProcess(project_settings)
        process.crawl(spider.MySpider)

        print("Starting crawler...")
        process.start()
    except Exception as err:
        logging.error("Error in the Airflow task !!!!!", err)
        raise CustomException("Error in the Airflow task !!!!!", err)
```

In this case when your custom exception will be raised, it will break the `Airflow` and mark it as failed.

Comment: It didn't work. Still the same =S

Comment: What is `CrawlerProcess` in your code ?

Comment: [CrawlerProcess](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/api.html#scrapy.crawler.CrawlerProcess) its the class I am using to call a spider.

Comment: I have the feeling that this launches a separate process and that Airflow does not wait for the response.

Comment: Actually, Airflow waits for it because while is crawling the task still green (running state). Maybe I should use middlewares to solve this problem, but I am not a pro in Scrapy...